# Windshield wipers on '98 Chevy S-10 work sometimes but not all the time

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, troubleshooting, windshield-wipers

I checked the fuse and wiring, they are okay, don't know what else it might be. BAFFLED. I think there is a motor and board, but don't know why it works sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: Welcome to SE Mechanics! Can you tell us more about the problem? It would be good to know what exactly happens that seems wrong – do the wipers not work at all? Do they work on any setting? Is there any pattern to when they work and when they don't? More information helps!

Comment: When they don't work, put the tranny in park and go outside and give them a tug.  If that doesn't help, go back in the cab and wiggle the control stalk a while to see if they start.  This isn't an answer, but some old-school shadetree tests that might help us narrow down the problem.

Comment: Do you hear a motor spinning but the wipers don't move? Is there a click when you turn them on but no other noise? There's not enough information here.

Comment: A friend of mine had wipers with a mind of their own in his '98 Silverado. He replaced the stalk in the steering column and all was well - He said it was a %@$#& of a project though, even for a highly experienced tinkerer.